# internal to external

Tags: google-play-store

I was wondering if there's a way that I can download apps from google play to my external sd card because every time I try downloading a game or a app it says "sorry, there's not enough storage on the device" and I have a 32gb sd card in and I tried going to applacation manager and moving apps manualy but some don't allow  me to move to my sd card and i have my default write disk on sd card and I have a samsung galaxy s5 mini

Answer (score 2):

If you have rooted your phone (if you do not know what root is then it is not rooted) try the app [foldermount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount), it may solve your problem. For more help moving an app to the external storage please watch this video I made: http://youtu.be/SUiZ_-B94Co